# YUI and Phantom/CasperJS : issue with Y.get callback

Tags: css, testing, yui, phantomjs, casperjs

I use YUI 3 as my main Javascript library and CasperJS for testing.

In my application I load CSS dynamically. I utilize `Y.Get.css` like this:

```
Y.Get.css(
    '#my_cssFile#',
    {
        attributes : {
            id : "#css_ID#"
        },
        async : true,
        onEnd : function () {
              myCallbackFunction();
        }
    }
);
```

When I run tests with CasperJS the `myCallbackFunction()` is never called.

I [read](http://www.phpied.com/when-is-a-stylesheet-really-loaded/) that some browsers have not implemented the `loadEvent` on `link` elements. CasperJs however, use a Webkit core. I suspect that something else is causing this.

I also tried using the `pollInterval` attribute, but with no result.

Is there a way to call a callback after loading CSS with casperJS?

Comment: I think you should open a bug. You'll probably get more help than here. Try https://github.com/yui/yui3/issues

Comment: Yes maybe, i will consider it. I wanted to know, first, if there are "StackOverflowers", who already had this bug. One of the points, is to known if it's YUI or CasperJS related.